# unsigned char limited to 127 on osx lion?

Tags: c++, unsigned-char

I am facing a strange issue, working on my mac osx lion (under xcode4/clang, though it is reproducible with gcc4.2).

It seems, that I can not assign any value above 127 for a unsigned char variable. So, when I assign

```
v = (unsigned char) 156;
```

or, simply

```
std::cout << (unsigned char) 231 << std::endl;
```

my program does not produce any output.

When I run this code

```
std::cout << "Unsigned chars range up to " << UCHAR_MAX << std::endl;
```

I get the following output:

Unsigned chars range up to 255

However, when I run something like this, the program generates outputs up to some different arbitrary value (such as c = 114, c = 252, etc etc) each time.
    for(unsigned char c = 0; c < CHAR_MAX; c++)
        std::cout << "c = " << 2*c << std::endl;

Changing the CHAR_MAX to UCHAR_MAX, the program ends without an output again :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your rationale is poor; use a debugger to debug, not a console. Try `v = (unsigned char)156; std::cout << (unsigned)v << '\n';`.

Comment: thanks! I was running it under gdb. type-casting to (`unsigned int`) did help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout` is converting the numeric value to a character from the character set (Well, it's attempting to ... when you don't see anything it's not a valid character for your charset, and technically it's the terminal that's deciding this).

Cast it to `unsigned int` instead.

**Edit to add:**  ildjarn makes a very valid point in his comment to your question; if you ran this in the debugger you'd see that the value was indeed what you expected.

Comment: "*Cast it to `int` instead.*" No, cast to `unsigned` instead, else risk unwanted sign-extension.

Answer (score 0):

What symbol are you expecting to see to represent character `(unsigned char)231`? On most systems, these are extended characters that need special terminal settings to be displayed as anything coherent if even visible.

Try this:

```
unsigned char testChar = (unsigned char)231;
unsigned int testInt = (unsigned int)testChar;
std::cout << testInt << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `unsigned char` is not limited to 127, however standard [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is only 7 bits (so 128 values). Any value above 127 does not represent any character (unless you use some kind of [extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)), so nothing is printed.